# Android: on pause, correct method to resume any activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

In an `onPause()` method within android, what is the correct method to ensure the `Activity` is resumed back to how it was previously?

For example if I wanted to pause and resume this `Activity`:

```
/**
 * Class containing an activity where the user enters an answer for each sum
 * within the times tables
 * 
 * @author Ross
 * 
 */
public class PracticeTest extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // declare variables
    int multiplier;
    int[] results = new int[12];
    int numberPassed;
    TextView question;
    EditText answer;
    ImageView image;
    int score;
    String[] questions = new String[12];
    MediaPlayer correctNoise;
    MediaPlayer incorrectNoise;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.practicetest);

        // / Setting int equal to int passed from previous activity (defaulted
        // to zero)
        numberPassed = getIntent().getIntExtra("convertedNumber2", 0);

        // Initialising variables
        correctNoise = MediaPlayer
                .create(PracticeTest.this, R.raw.correctnoise);
        incorrectNoise = MediaPlayer.create(PracticeTest.this,
                R.raw.incorrectnoise);
        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGoPractice2);
        answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnterNumberPractice2);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTopPractice2);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPracticeTest);

        // Setting on click listener for submit button
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        // update the question
        updateQuestion();

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        // sets text view equal to what is entered in editText
        final String entry = answer.getText().toString();

        // convert from string value to int
        int a = Integer.parseInt(entry); // note: maybe change name

        results[multiplier - 1] = a;

        // Displaying image and noise dependent on user answer
        if (a == numberPassed * multiplier) {

            correctNoise.start();
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsup);
            score++;

        } else {
            incorrectNoise.start();
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsdown);

        }

        if (multiplier < 12) {

            // called after an answer is given
            updateQuestion();

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PracticeResults.class);
            // Pass variables to next activity
            intent.putExtra("results", results);
            intent.putExtra("numberPassed", numberPassed);
            intent.putExtra("questions", questions);
            intent.putExtra("score", score);
            // Start new activity via intent
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method that updates question
     */
    public void updateQuestion() {
        // increase multiplier (i.e. 7x1 to 7x2 etc)
        multiplier++;
        // string to hold question
        String q = numberPassed + "x" + multiplier + "=";
        // Setting question equal to correct place in questions array
        questions[multiplier - 1] = q;
        // Set text in textView equal to the question
        question.setText(questions[multiplier - 1]);
        // change editText to be blank so a new answer can be entered
        answer.setText("");

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for. Give us more details and an example use case of expected behavior please.

Comment: This depends on what resouces you're using in your app. The rule of thumb is just to resume any activities your paused.

Answer (score 2):

See here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

[image: Activity Lifecycle]

Save your acivity

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Restore

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

1) Define what is the state of your activity. The state is all the data that fully describe how your activity looks and behaves at any given moment.

In your case you will want to save `question` and `answer` and `multiplier` and whatever else you have what is not calculated from other data.

2) Override `onSaveInstanceState()` and save your state in the bundle argument

3) In `onCreate` if `savedState` argument is not null then restore the state from the bundle and, based on the restore state, populate your Activity's views and whatever else should be initialized.

This way you guarantee the data will never be lost if your activity gets destroyed while paused.

Other than that it's good to pause any running processes  in `onPause` and resume then in `onResume`